# Count 2 aggregates using case in a nested and joined Select

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I hit a wall with the problem I was presented with by User...
Overview.
User requires statistic looking like this:

> `|TEAM | TARGET | WEEKLY | MONTHLY |
>   |-----|------- |--------|---------|
>   |AAA  | 80     | 15     | 59      |
>   |BBB  | 80     | 12     | 35      |
>   |CCC  | 80     | 13     | 50      |
>   |DDD  | 80     | 6      | 39      |
>   |EEE  | 80     | 7      | 28      |
>   |FFF  | 80     | 11     | 30      |
>   |GGG  | 80     | 10     | 28      |
>   |HHH  | 80     | 8      | 48      |`

I am at this point with the code:

```
DECLARE @StartExDate datetime
DECLARE @EndExDate datetime
declare @ThisWeekNow int
SET @StartExDate = (SELECT(CONVERT(DATETIME, (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1))))))
SET @EndExDate = (SELECT(CONVERT(DATETIME, (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))))))
SET @ThisWeekNow = (SELECT DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()))

Select 
    tt.Team
    ,tt.Target
    ,W_Total
    ,M_Total
From [Team_Targets] tt
        join (
                Select
                count(0) as M_Total,
                Case When DATEPART(wk,s.Date) = @ThisWeekNow Then count(1) end  as W_Total,
                m.FERef
                FROM [tr_type] s
                join [tr] c
                on s.ItemID = c.ItemID
                join [a] a
                on c.ParentID = a.ItemID
                join [M] m
                on a.ERef = m.ERef and a.MN = m.MN
                where s.Date between @StartExDate and @EndExDate
                        and (s.DRef = 1546 or s.DRef = 1658) 
                group by m.FERef, s.Date
                ) t
    on tt.team = t.FERef
    group by tt.team, tt.Target, t.M_Total, t.W_Total
```

What I get is this:

```
|TEAM | TARGET | WEEKLY | MONTHLY |
|-----|------- |--------|---------|
|AAA  | 80     | NULL   | 1       |
|AAA  | 80     | 1      | 1       |
|BBB  | 80     | NULL   | 1       |
|BBB  | 80     | 1      | 1       |
|CCC  | 80     | NULL   | 1       |
|CCC  | 80     | 1      | 1       |
|DDD  | 80     | NULL   | 1       |
|DDD  | 80     | 1      | 1       |
|EEE  | 80     | NULL   | 1       |
|EEE  | 80     | 1      | 1       |
|FFF  | 80     | NULL   | 1       |
|FFF  | 80     | 1      | 1       |
|GGG  | 80     | NULL   | 1       |
|GGG  | 80     | 1      | 1       |
|HHH  | 80     | NULL   | 1       |
|HHH  | 80     | 1      | 1       |
```

I'm a bit stumped.
If I drop one aggregate I get something useful.
Issue is that `Team_Targets` is an user table, while the rest is from off-the -shelf system we use, thus the `joins` and nested `selects`.
Is there a way to get the desired result? Any way will do. 
I'm this week on 3hrs of sleep a day, so I'm sure I'm missing something and/or using wrong function. Constant distractions at work don't help as well.
Hearty thanks for any and all suggestions.

Comment: Being on SQL 2012, have you tried using SUM() OVER(...)?  Check this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) (particularly Section B.)

Comment: The tables I'm working on are constantly used (INSERT heavy, also UPDATE), so I tried to do it a "all in one pass only" way. Over clause - if I remember correctly - caused query to be a bit long and lead to deadlocks. Or I did something wrong then and there. 
Sorry for quality of the answer, but as I stated in the problem: sleep deprivation and memories are a bit... foggy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Make your subquery return only one row for each FERef.

`DECLARE   @StartExDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndExDate DATETIME
DECLARE @ThisWeekNow INT
SET @StartExDate = (SELECT (CONVERT(DATETIME, (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1))))))
SET @EndExDate = (SELECT (CONVERT(DATETIME, (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))))))
SET @ThisWeekNow = (SELECT DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()))`

SELECT
    tt.Team,
    tt.Target,
    W_Total,
    M_Total
FROM
    [Team_Targets] tt
    JOIN (
            SELECT
                SUM(1) AS M_Total,
                SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(wk, s.Date) = @ThisWeekNow THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS W_Total,
                m.FERef
            FROM
                [tr_type] s
                JOIN [tr] c ON s.ItemID = c.ItemID
                JOIN [a] a ON c.ParentID = a.ItemID
                JOIN [M] m ON a.ERef = m.ERef AND a.MN = m.MN
            WHERE
                s.Date BETWEEN @StartExDate AND @EndExDate
                AND (s.DRef = 1546 OR s.DRef = 1658)
            GROUP BY m.FERef--, s.Date
    ) t ON tt.team = t.FERef
GROUP BY tt.team, tt.Target, t.M_Total, t.W_Total

Comment: Yep. That solved that. I suspected detail like that.

Comment: Looks like I slipped back to different db and query language....
Remember: whoever tells you switching between languages is easy is either selling something or lying.
Accepted as answer - works as intended.